# Configure `apt-get` to not have to get my confirmation for small packages?

Tags: apt, configuration

Currently, when I do something like a routine upgrade, it says something like this halfway through:

```
Need to get 42.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 36.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Realistically, there's *no* case when I'm gonna go, like:

"50 kB!? I had no idea what I was getting into here! I've changed my mind! Abort! Abort!"

So I'd like to disable this.

I'm not sure, but I *believe* there is already a maximum amount of data below which is doesn't bother prompting you...? So is there a number in a config file somewhere that I can just bump up, or...?

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/287348/why-does-apt-get-sometimes-asks-for-confirmation) explains when `apt` will ask for confirmation:

- Extra packages beyond the one in the request will be installed
- Important packages will be removed
- A held package is being changed

You can override the request once by adding the `-y` flag (`sudo apt-get install -y foobar`) or always by modifying the [`apt` configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/164553/automatically-answer-yes-when-using-apt-get-install).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is nothing in `apt` that prohibit downloading based on the download size. As **chronitis** said in his answer, you will be prompted for these reasons,

- Extra packages beyond the one in the request will be installed
- Important packages will be removed
- A held package is being changed

And yes, this confirmation is not for the size, it is more for the user awareness so that nothing is installed without confirmation. There is some security concerns also.